# End vba code if no value found

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to transfer data from one sheet to another. The code allows for the data being transferred to stay on the new sheet until deleted.

```
Private Sub Transfer2_Click()
Dim Work_Order1 As String, Qty1 As Integer, Frame1 As String, Qty_Frame1 As Integer
    Worksheets("Work_Order").Select
    if Worksheets("Work_Order").Range("C12") = "" Then Exit Sub
    Work_Order1 = Range("N3")
    Qty1 = Range("B3")
    Frame1 = Range("C12").Value
    Qty_Frame1 = Range("M12")
    Worksheets("Order").Select
    Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").Select
    If Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Work_Order1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Qty1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Frame1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Qty_Frame1

Private Sub Transfer2_Click()
Dim Work_Order2 As String, Qty2 As Integer, Frame2 As String, Qty_Frame2 As Integer
    Worksheets("Work_Order").Select
    if Worksheets("Work_Order").Range("C13") = "" Then Exit Sub
    Work_Order2 = Range("N3")
    Qty2 = Range("B3")
    Frame2 = Range("C13").Value
    Qty_Frame2 = Range("M13")
    Worksheets("Order").Select
    Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").Select
    If Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Work_Order2
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Qty2
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Frame2
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Qty_Frame2

Private Sub Transfer2_Click()
Dim Work_Order3 As String, Qty3 As Integer, Frame3 As String, Qty_Frame3 As Integer
    Worksheets("Work_Order").Select
    if Worksheets("Work_Order").Range("C14") = "" Then Exit Sub
    Work_Order1 = Range("N3")
    Qty3 = Range("B3")
    Frame3 = Range("C14").Value
    Qty_Frame3 = Range("M14")
    Worksheets("Order").Select
    Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").Select
    If Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Work_Order3
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Qty3
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Frame3
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Qty_Frame3
```

What I am trying to do is end this code is no value is found in the "C" Range. I have the code repeated nine times because there are nine instances where this info can be found, but not all will have values all the time. If that occurs, I want it to end the code before transferring info to the new sheet.

so far I've tried:

```
if Worksheets("Work_Order").Range("C12")="" Then
Exit sub
```

But it returns with the error Block if without end if.

Answer (score 0):

By putting the `Exit Sub` on a different line to the `If`, you are creating a "Block If", which needs an `End If`:

```
If Worksheets("Work_Order").Range("C12")="" Then
    Exit sub
End If
```

If you want to use a "single-line If", you should put your statements on a single line:

```
If Worksheets("Work_Order").Range("C12")="" Then Exit sub
```

---

Both statements work in exactly the same way, but "block Ifs" are usually easier to code when you have multiple statements to be executed within either the `True` or `False` leg of the statement.

E.g.

```
If a = 5 Then
    b = 7
    c = 10 * a - b
    d = 5 + b - c
Else
    b = 9
    c = 20 * a - 4 * b
    d = 6 + b + c
End If
```

is easier to read than

```
If a = 5 Then b = 7: c = 10 * a - b: d = 5 + b - c Else b = 9: c = 20 * a - 4 * b: d = 6 + b + c
```

---

In response to your comments, I am **guessing** that you don't actually want to `Exit Sub` when you hit a blank value, you want to instead go on to process the next range.

This could be done like this:

```
Private Sub Transfer2_Click()
    Dim Work_Order1 As String, Qty1 As Integer, Frame1 As String, Qty_Frame1 As Integer
    If Worksheets("Work_Order").Range("C12").Value <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Work_Order").Select
        Work_Order1 = Range("N3")
        Qty1 = Range("B3")
        Frame1 = Range("C12").Value
        Qty_Frame1 = Range("M12")
        Worksheets("Order").Select
        Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").Select
        If Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
            Worksheets("Order").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Select
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Work_Order1
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Qty1
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Frame1
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Qty_Frame1
    End If
    'Then repeat for the next set of cells
```

which can be rewritten to avoid the use of `Select` (which leads to so many problems) as

```
Private Sub Transfer2_Click()
    Dim Work_Order1 As String, Qty1 As Integer, Frame1 As String, Qty_Frame1 As Integer
    If Worksheets("Work_Order").Range("C12").Value <> "" Then
        With Worksheets("Work_Order")
            Work_Order1 = .Range("N3")
            Qty1 = .Range("B3")
            Frame1 = .Range("C12").Value
            Qty_Frame1 = .Range("M12")
        End With
        With Worksheets("Order").Cells(Worksheets("Order").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
            .Cells(1, "A").Value = Work_Order1
            .Cells(1, "B").Value = Qty1
            .Cells(1, "C").Value = Frame1
            .Cells(1, "E").Value = Qty_Frame1
        End With
    End If
    'Then repeat for the next set of cells
```

But it would be best if that was split into two subroutines to avoid a lot of repetitive code:

```
Private Sub Transfer2_Click()
    With Worksheets("Work_Order")
        Transfer2_Paste .Range("N3").Value, .Range("B3").Value, .Range("C12").Value, .Range("M12").Value
        'Then repeat for the next set of cells, e.g.
        'Transfer2_Paste .Range("N4").Value, .Range("B4").Value, .Range("C13").Value, .Range("M13").Value
        'etc
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Transfer2_Paste(Work_Order1 As String, Qty1 As Integer, Frame1 As String, Qty_Frame1 As Integer)
    If Frame1 = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With Worksheets("Order").Cells(Worksheets("Order").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
        .Cells(1, "A").Value = Work_Order1
        .Cells(1, "B").Value = Qty1
        .Cells(1, "C").Value = Frame1
        .Cells(1, "E").Value = Qty_Frame1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I made it a one line statement and altered it in the remaining code to check that range before proceeding to copy the data.

Comment: This worked great, but what if I wanted to skip that statement completely and proceed to the next one? I tried putting "on error resume next" if the value in the cell equals 0, but it still enters the 0's and then continues onto the next statement. I dont want it to enter anything, just basically skip that statement and move onto the next one.

Comment: @AshleyGoodwin Which statement are you trying to skip, and in what circumstances?  (The usual way to skip statements in certain circumstances is to wrap them with an `If` block, e.g. `If something is True Then` `do something` `do something else` `End If`, or `If something is True Then` `do something` `do something else` `Else` `do something when the test isn't True` `End If`.)

Comment: @AshleyGoodwin I have tried to make a guess at what you are trying to do, and have added a section to the end of the answer to show you a way to do it.

Comment: I went in and edited my code to try and explain what I'm looking for. Where I inserted the 'if Worksheets("Work_Order").Range("C#") = "" Then Exit Sub' is there a way to have it skip one statement and go to the next instead using on error resume next. Say C12 & C14 have a value, but C13 doesnt, the code I have with the resume next will still transfer data from C13 but as zeros across the sheet. Can I alter the code to have it skip over C13 and go straight to C14 if no value is found.

Comment: @AshleyGoodwin - see my edited answer where I attempted (correctly) to guess what you were trying to do.  (Well, **nearly** correctly - my guess of `Transfer2_Paste .Range("N4").Value, .Range("B4").Value, .Range("C13").Value, .Range("M13").Value` looks like it should have been `Transfer2_Paste .Range("N3").Value, .Range("B3").Value, .Range("C13").Value, .Range("M13").Value`)

Comment: @AshleyGoodwin - P.S. `On Error` statements are for handling errors, they are not replacements for `If` statements.